# data.table & column names

Tags: r, data.table

I am using `data.table` to get some basic statistics in one column while filtering by another column(s).

This is the command

```
stats <- as.data.frame(mydata[, j = list(Sum = sum(as.numeric(get(selection))),
                                         Average = mean(as.numeric(get(selection))),
                                         Count = length(get(selection))), 
                                by = list(get(filters))])
```

where:

- `mydata` is a `data.table` with 20 or so columns
- `selection` is a column name which is passed programmatically
- `filters` is also a column name which is passed programmatically

If I limit myself to one filter (one column) everything works, but I would like to filter by more than one column.

It is possible to do:

```
by = list(get(filters[1]), get(filters[2]), ...)
```

However, that requires I know how many filters will be used. That is a limitation I don't want to have.

How do I write the `by =` to take any number of filters (column names) - I just tried `mget(filters)` and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Data.tables `by` argument accepts a character vector of column names (see the documentation: `help("data.table")`). There is no need for `get`. Just use `by = c(filters)`.

Example:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(mtcars)

filters <- c("am", "gear")
DT[, mean(mpg), by=c(filters)]
#   am gear       V1
#1:  1    4 26.27500
#2:  0    3 16.10667
#3:  0    4 21.05000
#4:  1    5 21.38000
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something silly ... Thanks a bunch!